# Как получить координаты найденного цвета?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

Часть кода:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('example.png')
limit = np.array([255, 255, 255], dtype='uint8')

mask = cv2.inRange(image, limit, limit)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('images', output)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Каким образом можно получить (x, y) найденного цвета? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: координаты __всех__ точек?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Найти **все** координаты:

```
import numpy as np

y,x = np.where(mask != 0)
```

верхняя левая точка:

```
In [74]: print((x[0], y[0]))
(146, 80)
```

нижняя правая:

```
In [75]: print((x[-1], y[-1]))
(208, 92)
```